# How to convert an XString generated by ABAP to PDF?

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, node.js-addon

I have a PDF in XString format from ABAP.

I find that XString is an extended class of C++ Since node.js supports C++ am wondering how this XString can be handled and convert it into a PDF file in node.js.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: FWIW, in ABAP, the type [XSTRING](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abenbyte_string_glosry.htm) is a string of any number of **bytes**.

Comment: What does it have to do with ABAP?

Comment: Have you tried saving it with an extension of .pdf?

Comment: I really suggest you try to avoid adding C++ code to a Node.js application if you can avoid doing so, because it has many drawbacks. A `XString` is nothing but a series of bytes and can be represented in Node.js as a `Buffer`.